# how to animation speed slow when animation stop

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, cabasicanimation

My code is below. How can I speed slow when animation has stop?

```
extension UIView{
    func rotate() {
        let rotation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        rotation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotation.toValue = 25
        rotation.duration = 1.5
        rotation.isCumulative = true
        rotation.repeatCount = 1
        self.layer.add(rotation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    }
}
```

Comment: use completion block for slow animation

Comment: you can keep on reducing layer.speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find following details and add below line in your code,

```
rotation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
```

> **EaseInOut** An ease-in ease-out curve causes the animation to begin
>   slowly, accelerate through the middle of its duration, and then slow
>   again before completing. This is the default curve for most
>   animations.
>
> **EaseIn** An ease-in curve causes the animation to begin slowly, and then
>   speed up as it progresses.
>
> **EaseOut** An ease-out curve causes the animation to begin quickly, and
>   then slow down as it completes.

Hope this helps to you and let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `self.layer.speed` to decrease animation speed smoothly

You can do it like this

Note: You need to do some modification here it is not tested in xcode

```
  let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        self.layer.timeOffset = self.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
        if self.layer.speed == 0 { timer.invalidate() }
        self.layer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        self.layer.speed -= 0.5

    }
    timer.fire()
```

Hope it is helpful